# How to permanently delete interfaces from ifconfig?

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I want to permanently delete two interfaces from `ifconfig` in my Ubuntu 16.04. How to do this?

```
ifconfig <interface_name> down
```

does not persist across reboots.

Comment: Delete or disable interfaces? `ifconfig .. down` will not delete an interface. It will only make it offline...

Comment: I want to delete the interface.